# How to disable "just in time" debugger from visual studio 2008?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-2008

I have started to see this winlogon.exe crash when i installed visual studio 2008, could it be possible to disable "just in time debugger" because once i press "no" or shut off the dialog window, my computer shuts off. the same happens when i shut off winlogon.exe with process explorer...

I would like to disable that just-in-time-debugger because i never needed it and sometimes when a fullscreen program crashes i cant click the "no" button at all and i have to press reset button from my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be found under Tools... Options... Debugging... Just In Time. Uncheck "native code."

Answer (score 1):

You can disable JIT, You can find it in Visual studio 2008 under Options.